# How to add footnotes in TCDPF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF library and I want to add footnotes.

How can I do this from code?
Is there a "shortcut" or should I just edit the Footer() function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the footer function like for example:

```
class PDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Footer() {
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Some footer text');
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't encouter multiple footnotes and dynamic length of footnotes.